# Mapbox static api issue with bbox

Tags: mapbox

I am using the Mapbox static image API to download a bbox of an area of Yorkshire, in England.

Here's the URL I use

[https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v12/static/[-2.0,53.4,-1.2,54.0]/1000x750?access_token=XXXX](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v12/static/%5B-2.0,53.4,-1.2,54.0%5D/1000x750?access_token=XXXX)

I do get a nice image but it doesn't match the BBOX! in this case I am getting a large chunk of Manchester, which shouldn't be included. The API doc says a map "that fits the bbox" which I worry means the map chunk is larger than the actual BBOX. Is there a way to get the EXACT BBOX? I don't mind if the image is stretched. Something like a WMS request with BBOX. Or another service than mapbox maybe?

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy.  Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: What result do you get from https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/ ?

Comment: Nice I didn't know about the playground. So it looks like I need to adapt the width and height to the bbox, shame it's not working like a WMS service. Any idea about some other service that could give me what I want whithout recalculating the width and/or height?